# SSIS Project Deployment on Azure Data Factory pipeline including third party library like SSH.NET

Tags: azure, ssis, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, ssh.net

I am using SSH.NET library for SFTP access inside my SSIS project Script Task and I am using Visual Studio 2017 IDE. The project is working well on local. But when I am deploying it on the Azure Data Factory Pipeline it is throwing the below error.

[image]

**Error: Could not load file or assembly 'Renci.SshNet, Version=2016.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1cee9f8bde3db106' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.\n12/17/2019 12:58:22 PM +00:00 : Failed:Error: The script returned a failure result.\n",**

Please help in resolving this dll reference issue on Azure pipelines.

Thanks
Abhishek

Comment: You need to come up with an install script, and follow this guide to implement it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-configure-azure-ssis-ir-custom-setup If you have any specific questions please edit your question.